# Jquery dynamic selector error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When trying to change the text of an element using a dynamic selector I got Jquery error 
here is my Jquery code :

```
        var idx = ".counter-up,."+json.updates[i].key; 
        var old = parseInt($(idx).text());
```

I get the error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .counter-up,.`
http://jsfiddle.net/toulmek/CPAjC/

Comment: sorry for being that guy, json.updates[i].new_orders_no isn't undefined/null, right?

Comment: it's defined further up in the code

Comment: can you create this in a simple jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/toulmek/CPAjC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id cannot have spaces in it. It doesn't work like class where you can specify multiple values, the element can only have one id.

See this link: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: replace the comma with a space